# jquery mobile dialog in SSL

Tags: jquery-mobile, dialog

Since moving my JQM site to my live server I'm getting a few problems!

I have a dialog that appears using the slidedown transition on my test site.
When I move to my live site, it is loaded like an external page with no transition.

The reason for this is the URL for the dialog.

If I have the url as http://mysite.com/dialog.php it works perfectly with the slidedown transition.

If I have the url as https://mysite.com/dialog.php it loads with no transition.

It looks like using https rather than http is causing the issue.

Does anybody know a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Verify if your assets (js/css/images etc) are all served from secure url. There are browser policies that may restrict a secure url from loading non-secure assets.

Comment: Hi Kiran, I'm presuming the assets are all being served correctly because I don't get a warning about unsecure items from my browser and the javascript validation still works in the dialog but I don't really know how I'd verify.